# Get team's groups where the user is member, using Bitbucket API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

How to get a list of a team's groups where the user is member?
I found [this endpoint](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/groups+Endpoint#groupsEndpoint-GETalistofgroups) but in case the caller doesn't have administrative rights it always returns empty response

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you looking for is [user/privileges](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/user+Endpoint#userEndpoint-GETalistofuserprivileges) endpoint, from API v1.

**Example:**

GET https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user/privileges

**RESPONSE:**

```
{
    "teams": {
        "auserbb": "admin"
        "1team": "collaborator"
        "2team": "admin"
    }
}
```